# How can i get kendo scheduler current view on change view like day view or week view using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-scheduler

```
<kendo-scheduler [kendoSchedulerBinding]="events"
                 [selectedDate]="selectedDate"
                 [group]="group" [resources]="resources"
                 style="height: 600px;"
                 [workDayStart]="workDayStart" [workDayEnd]="workDayEnd" [showWorkHours]="true" (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)">
    <ng-template kendoSchedulerGroupHeaderTemplate let-resource="resource">
        <span [style.color]="resource?.color"><a  id="{{resource.text|split:'*':0}}" href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-unavilability">{{resource.text|split:'*':1}}</a></span>
    </ng-template>

    <kendo-scheduler-day-view>
    </kendo-scheduler-day-view>
    <kendo-scheduler-week-view>
    </kendo-scheduler-week-view>

</kendo-scheduler>
```

I have to get the current view of this kendo-scheduler (eg. day-view or week-view) in typescript and which view is by default selected in kendo-scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the index of the views is in the order of defining the views. So day-view is index 0, week-view is 1. Default is the first one. To set a different default you can use

```
 <kendo-scheduler [selectedViewIndex]="1" ...
```

to set the default to index 1. With that you can also use a variable to set the view index.